# Best way to setup MSTest for REST service with cookie-authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, mstest

Background: I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1, and integration testing a REST service that requires cookie authentication.

Candidate solution below.

Note:

- The reason I use a vanilla Host instead of TestServer is because of the cookie requirement. When using TestServer, it provides an HttpClient for you, but the client does not pass cookies back to the server.
- I also attempted to use a custom HttpClient with TestServer. That consistently generated a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApi; // Contains my Startup.cs

namespace WebApiTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UserTest
    {
        static IHost HttpHost;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static async Task ClassStartup(TestContext context)
        {
            HttpHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .Build();
            await HttpHost.StartAsync();
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static async Task ClassCleanup()
        {
            await HttpHost.StopAsync();
        }

        public static HttpContent GetHttpContent(object content)
        {
            HttpContent httpContent = null;

            if (content != null)
            {
                httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(content, content.GetType()));
                httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            }

            return httpContent;
        }

        public static HttpClient GetCookieHttpClient()
        {
            SocketsHttpHandler handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                UseCookies = true
            };

            return new HttpClient(handler);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetUserData_ReturnsSuccess()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = GetCookieHttpClient())
            {
                var credentials = new
                {
                    Email = "test@test.com",
                    Password = "password123",
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", GetHttpContent(credentials));
                response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("http://localhost:5000/api/users/{0}", credentials.Email));
                Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient` is a thin-client; it doesn't do anything unless you explicitly tell it to. In other words, it will never send the cookie for you; you must add a `Cookie` header to the request with the cookie value *for each request*. The test server "client" is just an `HttpClient` instance set up to proxy requests to the test server. You should use the test server, as prescribed, along with its client, and then add the `Cookie` header the requests you make with that.

Answer (score 1):

**Solutions based on Chris Pratt's suggestions**

After some further digging, Microsoft provides a solution for this (WebApplicationFactory):

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApi;

namespace WebApiTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Class2
    {
        static WebApplicationFactory<Startup> Factory;
        static WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions ClientOptions;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static async Task ClassStartup(TestContext context)
        {
            Factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
            ClientOptions = new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions();
            ClientOptions.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            ClientOptions.HandleCookies = true;
            ClientOptions.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        }

        public static HttpContent GetHttpContent(object content)
        {
            HttpContent httpContent = null;

            if (content != null)
            {
                httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(content, content.GetType()));
                httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            }

            return httpContent;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetUserData_ReturnsSuccess()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = Factory.CreateClient(ClientOptions))
            {
                var credentials = new
                {
                    Email = "test@test.com",
                    Password = "password123",
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", GetHttpContent(credentials));
                response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("http://localhost:5000/api/users/{0}", credentials.Email));
                Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In case you want to stick with TestServer, here is a manual Cookie-passing implementation:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApi;

namespace WebApiTest
{
    public class CookieHttpClient : IDisposable
    {
        private static HttpContent GetHttpContent(object content)
        {
            HttpContent httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(content, content.GetType()));
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return httpContent;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetCookieStrings(CookieCollection collection)
        {
            List<string> output = new List<string>(collection.Count);
            foreach (Cookie cookie in collection)
            {
                output.Add(cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private HttpClient client;
        private CookieContainer container;

        public CookieHttpClient(HttpClient client)
        {
            this.client = client;
            this.container = new CookieContainer();
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpMethod method, Uri uri)
        {
            return await this.SendAsync(method, uri, null);
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpMethod method, Uri uri, object data)
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);

            // Add data
            if (data != null)
            {
                request.Content = GetHttpContent(data);
            }

            // Add cookies
            CookieCollection collection = this.container.GetCookies(uri);
            if (collection.Count > 0)
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Cookie", GetCookieStrings(collection));
            }

            HttpResponseMessage response = await this.client.SendAsync(request);

            // Remember cookies before returning
            if (response.Headers.Contains("Set-Cookie"))
            {
                foreach (string s in response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie"))
                {
                    this.container.SetCookies(uri, s);
                }
            }

            return response;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.client.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Class1
    {
        static TestServer TestServer;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static async Task ClassStartup(TestContext context)
        {
            IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            TestServer = new TestServer(builder);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetUserData_ReturnsSuccess()
        {
            using (CookieHttpClient client = new CookieHttpClient(TestServer.CreateClient()))
            {
                var credentials = new
                {
                    Email = "test@test.com",
                    Password = "password123",
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login"), credentials);
                response = await client.SendAsync(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://localhost:5000/api/users/" + credentials.Email));
                Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```